# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable for Dikjstra python implementation

Tags: python, file, graph, dynamic-programming, dijkstra

I found the following implementation of dijksra's algorithm in python and I want to adjast it to my problem. The thing is that it throws an error when using a for-loop even though I haven't changed anything in the code!

I want to save each vertex to a list or array, get an input vertex from the user as a destination vertex and then with a for-loop get all the paths from every vertex to the destination and calculate their costs
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is the code

```
from collections import deque, namedtuple


# we'll use infinity as a default distance to nodes.
inf = float('inf')
Edge = namedtuple('Edge', 'start, end, cost')


def make_edge(start, end, cost=1):
  return Edge(start, end, cost)


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges):
    # let's check that the data is right
    wrong_edges = [i for i in edges if len(i) not in [2, 3]]
    if wrong_edges:
        raise ValueError('Wrong edges data: {}'.format(wrong_edges))

    self.edges = [make_edge(*edge) for edge in edges]

@property
def vertices(self):
    return set(
        sum(
            ([edge.start, edge.end] for edge in self.edges), []
    )
)

def get_node_pairs(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
    if both_ends:
        node_pairs = [[n1, n2], [n2, n1]]
    else:
        node_pairs = [[n1, n2]]
return node_pairs

def remove_edge(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
    node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
    edges = self.edges[:]
    for edge in edges:
        if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
            self.edges.remove(edge)

def add_edge(self, n1, n2, cost=1, both_ends=True):
    node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
    for edge in self.edges:
        if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
            return ValueError('Edge {} {} already exists'.format(n1, n2))

    self.edges.append(Edge(start=n1, end=n2, cost=cost))
    if both_ends:
        self.edges.append(Edge(start=n2, end=n1, cost=cost))

@property
def neighbours(self):
    neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
    for edge in self.edges:
        neighbours[edge.start].add((edge.end, edge.cost))

return neighbours

def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
    assert source in self.vertices, 'Such source node doesn\'t exist'
    distances = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
    previous_vertices = {
        vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices
    }
    distances[source] = 0
    vertices = self.vertices.copy()

    while vertices:
        current_vertex = min(
            vertices, key=lambda vertex: distances[vertex])
        vertices.remove(current_vertex)
        if distances[current_vertex] == inf:
            break
        for neighbour, cost in self.neighbours[current_vertex]:
            alternative_route = distances[current_vertex] + cost
            if alternative_route < distances[neighbour]:
                distances[neighbour] = alternative_route
                previous_vertices[neighbour] = current_vertex

    path, current_vertex = deque(), dest
    while previous_vertices[current_vertex] is not None:
        path.appendleft(current_vertex)
        current_vertex = previous_vertices[current_vertex]
    if path:
        path.appendleft(current_vertex)
    return path


with open('city1.txt') as fp:
    dataset = [line.split() for line in fp.readlines() if line]


for connection in dataset:
    connection[2] = int(connection[2])


graph = Graph(dataset)


verteces = []
for set in dataset:
    if set[0] not in verteces:
        verteces.append(set[0])
    if set[1] not in verteces:
        verteces.append(set[1])

print(verteces)

destination = input("Enter destination point: ")
verteces.remove(destination)

for vertex in verteces:
    print(graph.dijkstra(str(vertex), str(destination)))
```

and here is the file

```
A B 2
A E 2
A W 1
B D 5
B W 4
B C 2
B F 3
C F 7
C V 9
D E 1
D J 7
E K 3
F L 2
F M 7
F R 3
F Y 1
G K 8
G J 5
G H 2
H I 4
H P 1
I K 5
J O 3
J L 2
L N 4
N O 1
O P 1
M N 5
M Z 3
M X 1
Z N 6
X Z 2
Y X 5
R S 4
S V 2
```

error

```
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/dijkstra/main.py", line 122, in <module>
    print(graph.dijkstra("A", "B"))
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/dijkstra/main.py", line 63, in 
dijkstra
assert source in self.vertices, 'Such source node doesn\'t exist'
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/dijkstra/main.py", line 26, in vertices
([edge.start, edge.end] for edge in self.edges), []
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback of your error to help understand where the problem is occurring

Comment: just added the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redefined the `set` function in:

```
for set in dataset:
    .....
```

So when you call `dijkstra`, `set` is no longer the builtin function, but one of the lists in dataset.

So, in:

```
def vertices(self):
    return set(
        sum(
            ([edge.start, edge.end] for edge in self.edges), []
    )
)
```

trying to call `set` fails.

Just change the name of the variable, and remember not to use builtin functions names as variable names!

Comment: Thanks, you are the best